# Explain notation in Hartshorne about localization ring of projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Thm 3.4 in Hartshorne and comments above it, it says: "Similarly, if $f \in S$ is a homogeneous element, we denote by $S_{(f)}$ the subring of elements of degree $0$ in the localized ring $S_{f}$."

Now, in this case, what is the multiplicative set of the localized ring $S_{f}$; is it just $\{f\}$ or the ideal generated by f i.e. $(f)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the set of powers of $f$, not the ideal.

Comment: So $\{f^k |$ f homogeneous element, $k \geq 0$ and $k$ integer $\}$?

Comment: @metalder9 The function field is the $\frac{u}{v}$ with $ u,v$ homogeneous polynomials of same degree (for a sub-projective variety $X$ you need also that $v$ doesn't vanish identically on $X$) and $S_{(f)}$ is the subring of the $\frac{u}{f^k}$ with $u$ homogeneous polynomial of degree $k \deg(f)$

Comment: @reuns Oh, I wrote my question wrong, what I meant is the multiplicative set of $S_{f}$ actually $S - \{f\}$ instead of $\{f\}$, but it turns out (confirm pls) that the multiplicative set of $S_{f}$ is the set of powers of . Thanks for clarifying as well, in the case of a variety. Hence, I am assuming this is the same for $k[x_1,...,x_n]_{(x_i)}$, subring of $\frac{u}{x_i^k}$.